# php youtube api v3 description fetch issue

Tags: php, youtube

they say in documentation  in a video resource, the snippet property contains the channelId, title, description, tags, and categoryId properties. my code blew

```
$main=ngegrab('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&contentDetails&statistics&id=0W55Oed_Uic&key=AIzaSyD7o2nlYk-a57KEXHfW4QNZ1Z6nhE-4x0g');
$sub=json_decode($main);
foreach ($sub->items as $item){
$name = $item->snippet->title;
$des = $item->snippet->description;
$vid = $item->id->videoId;
```

when i try echo to print $name giving video name but $des not giving description and $vid not giving the video id

Comment: Did you try to read your JSON ? ... https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&contentDetails&statistics&id=0W55Oed_Uic&key=AIzaSyD7o2nlYk-a57KEXHfW4QNZ1Z6nhE-4x0g

Comment: plz details how i red my JSON ?

Comment: Did you click the link in my comment ... ? do you understand what you do ?

Comment: yeas that right all info is correct but that info not getting my web page with curl

Comment: You should stop for today, take a good coffee and think ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Description is empty for this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0W55Oed_Uic so it will be empty try any other video.